Ubuntu / Ubuntu Unity 24.04 blank desktop after installing caja file manager
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 with Unity and later Ubuntu Unity 24.04. Everything worked fine in both cases. I use Caja File Manager, so, I installed it and then rebooted the system. After the reboot, I logged in but I am seeing a blank desktop now. No top bar, no dock, not even the mouse cursor. Only wallpaper is showing.
I tried several fixes like reinstalling Unity Desktop, deleting the compiz folder under the .config folder, and resetting Unity sid, but none resolved the issue.
I rebooted the machine in recovery mode and uninstalled Caja File from the command line. I restarted the machine and everything was working fine. No blank desktop, dock and top bar available. Just to confirm the theory that Caja file manager causing the blank desktop issue, I installed it again rebooted the machine, and logged in. Again a blank desktop.
Does anybody have any idea why Caja File Manager could be causing this issue and how to fix it?
Machine details just in case needed -

Lenovo ThinkCentre - M10q
No graphics cards like NVDIA
Quad-core
16 GB ram
500 GB NVME storage.

